# jQuery plugins / functions not loading after rails 3.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I just recently upgraded a large project to rails 3.1.  I've got the asset pipeline set up and working.  However, a lot of the plugins we use and the custom jQuery functions we've written don't seem to be getting evaluated, although the source is in application.js.  For example:

```
   (function($) {
     $.fn.searchable = function() {
        ....
     }
   })( jQuery );
```

I see this code in application.js, but anything that tries to use it gets a javascript error, undefined function.  However, if I wrap the whole thing in a function definition, and call that function on document ready, then it works.

This is a really ugly workaround.  Any ideas why it's not working without wrapping in a function?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh the pain!  I too recently (6 months ago) upgraded two large 2.3.8 apps to 3.[1|2].  I remember the same kinds of issues.  I wish I could remember all the details of what I went through,  but I don't (I'm too old!).  What I do remember is that at one point, out of frustration,  I pre-compiled the assets in development.  I can only remember that it was a key to breaking the log jam,  it somehow revealed the ultimate answers, (for a lot of my specific cases).  Seems counter intuitive!  Wish I could help more!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should take a look at 'coffeescript's namescope'. e.g.

```
//define your js function as: 
this.some_function_name()  => 
  alert('hello~')

//call it as:
this.some_function_name()
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem of other plugins that are already written and usually minified.